# Proper term for "four way duel"

Tags: single-word-requests

On this Wednesday's *Survivor*, Jeff Probst called one of the challenges as a "four way duel."

Now, obviously, this is wrong because a duel is between two opponents, but is there a term referring to a fight between four opponents?

Comment: Uno, duo, tre, quattro. Could it be a quarrel? Or a quattrel?

Comment: If 'quad-bike' is acceptable, 'four-way duel' shouldn't be too problematic.

Answer (score 6):

It would probably be best to say "a four-way contest".

Answer (score 3):

To quote wikipedia:

> Battle royal (plural battles royal) traditionally refers to a fight involving three or more combatants that is fought until only one fighter remains standing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Royal

"Battle Royale" is a Japanese novel that has had many adaptations.

Comment: Well, you may not actually have answered the question, but that's certainly an interesting path you've taken me half-way down. If we allow that *imperial* is higher up the pecking order than *royal*, perhaps we could coin the neologism *Battle imperial*.

Answer (score 2):

Why, it's a [squirmish](http://www.businessinsider.com/sarah-palin-squirmish-libya-video-2011-3) of course!

Comment: You should really post the proper word as well: "Scaramouche".  No, that doesn't sound right.  (it's "Skirmish")

Comment: Etymologically, I think I'd further transmogrify that to "squarmish". Then "squintmish" for five, "shexmish" for six...

Answer (score 2):

If Mr. Probst was familiar with Old Latin, he would not be wrong! *Duellum* is the old form of *bellum* meaning 'war' and was only later in the Medieval period found in poetry and reinterpreted as being related to *duo* and was concluded to mean 'a battle of two.' (See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duellum))

It does seem the word is wandering back to just meaning 'fight, showdown' regardless of the number of opponents... Language changes or how my historical linguistics professor put it: "Shift happens."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is good. I'll share this from the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/duel_n?tab=etymology#6089264): "The Latin form duellum is well attested in ancient inscriptions and retained in classical Latin literature in archaic language and in poetry; in post-classical Latin it is also used specifically to denote a fight between two combatants (11th cent.; frequently from 12th cent. in British sources). This specific use was probably influenced by duo two (see duo n.)." Then the OED quotes 7th century writer Isidore, who guessed *duellum* was related to duo.

Answer (score 1):

In French and Italian they say *quadrangular* but that did not catch up in English I believe.

Although you have a number of hits for **quadrangular fight**, a possible reference to wrestling or other "ring" combat sports.

Answer (score 1):

Or a "four-way battle". Or simply just "battle" would do..